# .NET Maui Map Pin doesn't reset on iOS

Tags: maui

I have this code:

```
private async void Pin_MarkerClicked(object sender, PinClickedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var popup = new PinPopUp(Convert.ToInt64(((Pin)sender).ClassId));
        App.Current.MainPage.ShowPopup(popup);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Crashes.TrackError(ex);            
    }
}
```

which loads a popup when you click on a pin. On Android when you dismiss the popup you can click immediately on the same pin and the event will fire again, no issues.

On iOS the pins seems to have a 'selected/active' state that gets engaged after pin click (the pin appears larger on the screen) and after the popup is dismissed, the only way to select the pin again is to click on another pin or on the map to get the pin in the 'unselected' state, and then the user can re-select the pin.

Is there a way to reset the pin to make it selectable again? I see nothing applicable in the PIN properties or methods.

Comment: I tested it based on the code provided by Maui’s official documentation. Clicking on the Pin pop-up warning window can be triggered again after it is closed. Can you try to change your click event to see if repeated clicks will trigger it? You can refer to the official sample:[.NET MAUI - Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/maui-samples/userinterface-map/)

Comment: I changed my click event to only display an alert as per the example and got the same behavior.

Comment: It's the e.HideInfoWindow = true that resets it. Kind of a misnomer as it's not actually hiding the info window. But whatever it works now! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the Pin_InfoWindowClicked event you set e.HideInfoWindow = true, this keeps the pin in a state that's ready to be clicked again on iOS. I don't think that's a great name for that property as it doesn't actually hide your info window (thankfully) on iOS. It does hide it on Android so I had to put in a check to not add this line for Android.

Comment: You can accept it as answer(click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue. Thanks in advance!